# React-Native authentication and Cloud Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement authentication to Cloud Firestore but dont know if I need to add Two Apps in the project settings of the project in Firebase or I just need one?
The main thing where I am totally confused is that the Cloud-Firestore docs say that I need to create a Web app in the Firebase Project, and on the other side I need an Android app in the same Firebase project for the authentication. So, how are those two communicating with each other, how my users are registered to one of the apps and given access to the other app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create two Firbase apps, you only need to create one Firbase app and link it to your Android App.

1. In the Firebase Console you have to `+ Add project`.
2. In the project that you have create, under **Get started by adding Firebase to your app** you have to click on Android icon. This will create a Firebase Application for android.
3. There you will have to register the details of your Android Application. e.g. **Android package name** etc.
4. Then it will prompt you to download the JSON configuration file that you will have to include in your Android App.
5. After that you will have successfully linked your Firebase Project Application to your Android App

For more detailed explanation I advice you to follow the [Add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) documentation.

Comment: this doesnt answer my question, I asked how does authentication works with Cloud Firestore. How do users authenticate to my DB using for ex. Google authentication?

Comment: Currently I have implemented Google auth but I can also access my db without having to login, how do I prevent that?

Comment: just fixed it, my db was public so anyone could fetch or post anything.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I am glad that you found the solution.

Comment: btw do you know whats the best way to persist user session throughout all pages? I am still using Google auth.

Comment: If by **pages** you mean **Android Activities**, then I believe that this is the best way to continue the session. As per [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) and [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) you authenticate the user with `FirebaseAuth` and you get the logged in user with `FirebaseUser`. Otherwise more options would be mentioned in the public documentation.

Comment: I need to keep the session throughout any activity in the app (React Native) so that the user has access to everything using that session (or cookie)

Comment: As far as I understand you are developing a cross platform app using React Native with Node.js. I am also authenticating users using `FirebaseAuth` and they are always authenticated with that method across all pages. I am currently developing an Ionic 4 app with Firebase auth. Since the Firebase app is linked through the environments variables (in my case), I just import `FirebaseAuth` module in every page and checking the current session if there is any user signed in. If I sign in through page `/home` and I check the user in page `/another_page`, I will still be able to take his details.